# Balcony tree which can be kept in winter in appartment

Tags: houseplants, plant-care

I am looking for a small tree/plant up to 2.5m high, which can be kept in the winter months in the apartment, I.e. sunny and about 20 degrees C, otherwise on balcony. live in Austria, rather warm summer (up to 35C), cold winters (-15C).

I am only aware of trees which should be kept in winter around 10C and rather dark.

Comment: It depend on the tree (species), so what characteristic you are looking.

Comment: I do not get the comment. I have written which properties the tree should have. What should I still specify?